# Wordpress notice offset when reading json data

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I've the data from json like this

```
"rajaongkir":{
"result":{
"manifest":[
        {
           "manifest_code":"1",
           "manifest_description":"Manifested",
           "manifest_date":"2015-03-04",
           "manifest_time":"03:41",
           "city_name":"xxxx"
        },
        {
           "manifest_code":"2",
           "manifest_description":"On Transit",
           "manifest_date":"2015-03-04",
           "manifest_time":"15:44",
           "city_name":"xxxx"
        },
        {
           "manifest_code":"3",
           "manifest_description":"Received On Destination",
           "manifest_date":"2015-03-05",
           "manifest_time":"08:57",
           "city_name":"xxxx"
        }
     ]
```

And I want to show the data above to the table so I create the code like below

```
$decode=json_decode($response, true);
<?php
    for($j=0; $j < count($decode['rajaongkir']['result']); $j++)
    {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $decode['rajaongkir']['result']['manifest'][$j]['manifest_date']; ?> <?php echo $decode['rajaongkir']['result']['manifest'][$j]['manifest_time']; ?></td><td><?php echo $decode['rajaongkir']['result']['manifest'][$j]['city_name']; ?></td><td><?php echo $decode['rajaongkir']['result']['manifest'][$j]['manifest_description']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

The data shown correctly but after the table, I have the notice Notice: Undefined offset: 2. in .... until Notice: Undefined offset: 4. in.....

Do you know how to fix this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've got it, my fault is in the pattern.

When the pattern is correct, the notice was gone